# Are there omissions of and or to, or are they bare infinitivals?

Tags: conjunctions, infinitives

> "I'll run go get a taxi" ([about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/Serial-Verbs.htm))

This construction is called as serial verb one by about.com and Prof. [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57707/im-going-to-take-and-stir-the-cake-mix/57776#57776). While it is as *catenative verbs construction* by wictionry.org and CGEL: “
catenative verbs are verbs which can be followed directly by another verb — variously in the *to-infinitive, bare infinitive or present participle/gerund* forms. ([wictionary.org](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs))”; “which take non-finite complements (CGEL,p.104)”.

There being two ways of seeing the construction, it’s not clear whether it can be understood as ‘I’ll run and go and get a taxi’ or ‘I’ll run (to) go (to) get a taxi’. I guess there isn’t that big difference between the two. For to-infinitvals can denote sequential or simultaneous occurrence of the actions or the result of previous action - or the effect of switching scenes: I run, click, going, click, getting a taxi.

What I wanted to know is which one –– omission of *and (conjunction)*, or omission of *to (subordinator)* or bare infinitival –– you natives have in your mind when you say them.

Comment: I'm fine with *go get*, *come see*, *go fetch*, *come play*, and so on.  These all fit into what Arnold Zwicky calls [the Quasi-Serial Verb (QSV) construction](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005039.html).  But *run go get*?  To my ear, it's flatly ungrammatical.  (Your English May Vary.)

Comment: My English is the same. I can't imagine hearing or saying such a phrase. I would say "I'll run to get a taxi". "go" is not needed because its implied.

Comment: What @snailplane said. It doesn't sound good to me either, and I'd advise learners not to get involved with **run go get**. The more "normal" case of two consecutive verbs can generally be understood as having an implied intervening **and** elided. It's overanalysis to suppose that in *some* contexts you could substitute **to** or **for**, for example.

Comment: By the way, the answer is neither.  I don't think I'm ellipting anything when I say *go see*.

Comment: More by Zwicky on QSVs: http://arnoldzwicky.org/2012/08/28/qsv/

Comment: @snailplane, Thank you very much for the links. Without them, I would have stuck to catenative or something.

Comment: I hear it as the conjunctive case. Such a statement sounds to me like the speaker dropped the word "and" by accident. "I'll run and go get" sounds more natural than "I'll run to go get".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I personally think of it as the conjunction case, with the simplification that comes without having to include the actual conjunction.  However, in terms of presenting the meaning of the quasi-serial verb, I think the omission of "to" makes more sense, but would sound more strange than the conjunctive version if both are said out loud.

Comment: In OP's *specific* example, it's nonsensical to suggest *"I'll run **to** go..."* as a credible "original".

Comment: Could you explain further?  It is not clear to me why I am being down voted for this. The OP asked for a native speaker opinion and that is what I gave.  Rereading, it still seems like it would make more sense in the quasi-serial verb sense of "run (to) go (to) ..." as those are actions happening simultaneously, where-as "run (and) go (and) ..." has a more "I'll do this, then this, then this" meaning to it. I certainly wouldn't advocate writing in either style, but my opinion is for the colloquial usage.

Comment: @CG-K, I appreciate you've shown me a good way for natives how to think about the structure.

Comment: @CG-K: Imho, OP's three-verb sequence is simply daft anyway, but *run **to** go* is even dafter.